# Visual Studio error upon opening scripts from Unity Project and Sound effects not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, soundeffect

For the last couple of days, I have been trying to fix a problem, and after little success, I have brought it to you to plead for you assistance.

The short version of my problem is that sound effects will not play in my game, and every time I open Visual Studio, I get an error about not being able to load the solution, and it only open the specific script I clicked on, with no connection to the rest of the project.

For context, this Unity project worked fine, and I have never seen this issue before. Then, I tried to add a specific sound effect to my game.

After adding the sound effect, everything worked fine, until I tried to play the sound effect, where I then noticed that all sound effects had stopped. not only that, even after restarting the scene and reopening Unity, sound effects still would not play. I even deleted the sound effect that I believe caused the issue, but things still would not work.

While troubleshooting for that issue, I tried to open Visual Studio to see if there was an issue with the code, only to find out that every time I open VS for that specific project, I get an error about not being able to load the solution. This does not happen to any of my other projects, just this one. I am starting to get worried that I may have to delete my project and start it over from scratch.

Comment: What version of Unity are  you using? There are different ways of connecting your Visual Studio project to Unity in settings depending on which version you use.

Comment: Please post pictures of the following windows: Package Manager -> In Unity Project, Preferences -> External Tools and Player -> Configuration (only the Configuration section for now). Also tell us the current platform on which you develop and the target platform please! Since we might not know the problem and will attempt "trial & error", also perform a backup of your whole project directory. Also answer @CoolPerson879 's question as well.

Comment: I am using unity version 2022.1.10f1, & visual studios 2019 for mac.

I am new to this site and dont know how to add pictures though